# pass parameters to a wrapper url - Joomla3.x

Tags: template-override, wrapper

I have a requirement to pass parameters from the joomla calling URL to the wrapper iframe URL.

I had a look around to see if I could do this and found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200934/pass-value-in-url-to-wrapped-url-in-joomla-2-5 for J2.5 version, which suggests customising the core wrapper files to achieve this

```
Find $url = $params->def('url', '');

Then add the following after it (as outlined in Abid's link)

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  if ($key<>"option" && $key<>"Itemid") {
    $url.=(strpos($url,"?")) ? "&" : "?";
    $url.="$key=$value";
  }
}
```

So that is parsing the calling URL and adding the params to the of it

But customising core is generally a bad idea. I was wondering if it might be possible to achieve the same outcome using a template override?

I have created an override from /html/com_wrapper/wrapper/default.php

In there the iframe code is as follows:

```
<iframe <?php echo $this->wrapper->load; ?>
    id="blockrandom"
    name="iframe"
    src="<?php echo $this->escape($this->wrapper->url); ?>"
    width="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('width')); ?>"
    height="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('height')); ?>"
    scrolling="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('scrolling')); ?>"
    frameborder="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('frameborder', 1)); ?>"
    class="wrapper<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php echo JText::_('COM_WRAPPER_NO_IFRAMES'); ?>
</iframe>
```

So is it possible to add that same foreach logic into this code ?

And would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write the logic into the default.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_wrapper
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('script', 'com_wrapper/iframe-height.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));

$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();

$wrapper = new stdClass;

// Auto height control
if ($params->def('height_auto'))
{
        $wrapper->load = 'onload="iFrameHeight()"';
}
else
{
        $wrapper->load = '';
}

$url = $params->def('url', '');

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  if ($key<>"option" && $key<>"Itemid") {
    $url.=(strpos($url,"?")) ? "&" : "?";
    $url.="$key=$value";
  }
}

if ($params->def('add_scheme', 1))
{
        // Adds 'http://' or 'https://' if none is set
        if (strpos($url, '//') === 0)
        {
                // URL without scheme in component. Prepend current scheme.
                $wrapper->url = JUri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme')) . substr($url, 2);
        }
        elseif (strpos($url, '/') === 0)
        {
                // Relative URL in component. Use scheme + host + port.
                $wrapper->url = JUri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme', 'host', 'port')) . $url;
        }
        elseif (strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0 && strpos($url, 'https://') !== 0)
        {
                // URL doesn't start with either 'http://' or 'https://'. Add current scheme.
                $wrapper->url = JUri::getInstance()->toString(array('scheme')) . $url;
        }
        else
        {
                // URL starts with either 'http://' or 'https://'. Do not change it.
                $wrapper->url = $url;
        }
}
else
{
        $wrapper->url = $url;
}

$this->params        = &$params;
$this->wrapper       = &$wrapper;

?>
<div class="contentpane<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <?php if ($this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading'))) : ?>
                <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<iframe <?php echo $this->wrapper->load; ?>
    id="blockrandom"
    name="iframe"
    src="<?php echo $this->escape($this->wrapper->url); ?>"
    width="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('width')); ?>"
    height="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('height')); ?>"
    scrolling="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('scrolling')); ?>"
    frameborder="<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('frameborder', 1)); ?>"
    class="wrapper<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php echo JText::_('COM_WRAPPER_NO_IFRAMES'); ?>
</iframe>
</div>
```

If you don't need the sheme logic again and just want to add the params to the url, you can reduce it to:

```
    $url = $this->wrapper->url;
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
      if ($key<>"option" && $key<>"Itemid") {
        $url.=(strpos($url,"?")) ? "&" : "?";
        $url.="$key=$value";
      }
    }

    $this->wrapper->url = $url;
```